# Use cases for functor/applicative/monad instances for functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Haskell has `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` instances defined for functions (specifically the partially applied type `(->) a`) in the standard library, built around function composition.

Understanding these instances is a nice mind-bender exercise, but my question here is about the practical uses of these instances. I'd be happy to hear about realistic scenarios where folks used these for some practical code.

Comment: The [Reader monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html) is basically just a newtype wrapper around `(->)`.

Comment: I use them all the time. Probably you do it yourself without knowing: `.` is just `fmap`.

Comment: @Bergi: sure, I guess the question is why use them instead of just using (.)

Comment: @Bergi Composition exists independently of the `Functor` instance; it is more accurate to say that `fmap` is just `.`.

Answer (score 7):

A common pattern that involves Functor and Applicative instances of functions is for example `(+) <$> (*2) <*> (subtract 1)`. This is particularly useful when you have to feed a series of function with a single value. In this case the above is equivalent to `\x -> (x * 2) + (x - 1)`. While this is very close to `LiftA2` you may extend this pattern indefinitely. If you have an f function to take 5 parameters like `a -> a -> a -> a -> a -> b` you may do like `f <$> (+2) <*> (*2) <*> (+1) <*> (subtract 3) <*> (/2)` and feed it with a single value. Just like in below case ;

```
Prelude> (,,,,) <$> (+2) <*> (*2) <*> (+1) <*> (subtract 3) <*> (/2) $ 10
(12.0,20.0,11.0,7.0,5.0)
```

**Edit:** Credit for a re-comment of @Will Ness for a comment of mine under another topic, here comes a beautiful usage of applicative over functions;

```
Prelude> let isAscending = and . (zipWith (<=) <*> drop 1)
Prelude> isAscending [1,2,3,4]
True
Prelude> isAscending [1,2,5,4]
False
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. So the 5-tuple example you posted. It can be rewritten as `(\x -> (x+2, x*2, x+1, x-3, x/2)) 10` -- the advantage of the applicative here is that there's no need to repeat `x`?

Comment: @Eli Bendersky The main difference is, in the applicative form if you know how many parameters the main function takes, the whole thing is functionally decomposable (that you can dynamically compose the parameters the way you like) while in lambda form you have to have a solid lambda function at hand.

Comment: are you saying that we already have a function, like `(,,,,)` and don't have to write the lambda by hand?

Comment: @Eli Bendersky Yes... This whole thing might be another function definition which takes the applying functions `(+2)`, (*2), (+1), (subtract 3) and (/2)` as parameters and you may replace `subtract 3` with `subtract 1` and apply it.

Comment: I guess I can sort-of see what you are trying to say, but it's hard for me to envision without a concrete use case :)

Comment: @Eli Bendersky I mean the lambda function `(\x -> (x+2, x*2, x+1, x-3, x/2))` would be hard wired while in applicative style it wouldn't. One can make up a new function with the applicative one to change the "mapping" functions dynamically. A concrete use case... is hard to come up with spontaneously but this is a good knowledge to have in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you want to treat functions of the form `a -> m b` (where `m` is an `Applicative`) as `Applicative`s themselves. This often happens when writing validators, or parsers.

One way to do this is to use `Data.Functor.Compose`, which piggybacks on the `Applicative` instances of `(->) a` and `m` to give an `Applicative` instance for the composition:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Functor.Compose

type Star m a b = Compose ((->) a) m b

readPrompt :: Star IO String Int
readPrompt = Compose $ \prompt -> do
    putStrLn $ prompt ++ ":"
    readLn

main :: IO ()
main = do
    r <- getCompose (liftA2 (,) readPrompt readPrompt) "write number"
    print r
```

There are other ways, like creating your own newtype, or using [ready-made](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:WrappedArrow) [newtypes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2.1/docs/Data-Profunctor.html#t:Star) from *base* or other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

here an application of the bind function that I used for solving the Diamond Kata. Take a simple function that mirrors its input discarding the last element

```
mirror :: [a] -> [a]
mirror xs = xs ++ (reverse . init) xs
```

let's rewrite it a bit

```
mirror xs = (++) xs ((reverse . init) xs)
mirror xs = flip (++) ((reverse . init) xs) xs
mirror xs = (reverse . init >>= flip (++)) xs
mirror = reverse . init >>= flip (++)
```

Here is my complete implementation of this Kata: https://github.com/enolive/exercism/blob/master/haskell/diamond/src/Diamond.hs

Comment: Since `ma >>= f` equals `flip f <*> ma` you can limit yourself to the `Applicative` instance of functions, i.e. `mirror = (++) <*> reverse . init`. Not using `(>>=)` and the `Monad` instance of functions seems to be reasonable.