# Haskell monad for isPalindrome

Tags: haskell, monads

The 6th of the 99 Haskell questions on [wiki.haskell.org](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/Solutions/6) presents a monadic way to test whether a list (something of type `[a]`) is a palindrome:

```
isPalindromeM :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
isPalindromeM = reverse >>= (==)
```

(here `reverse :: [c] -> [c]` takes a list and outputs a list in backwards order).

The bind operation implies a monad is at play here, but what is this monad?

Since isPalindrome involves lists, my first guess is that the monad is related to the List one, but I don't see how to draw the connection.

Comment: [Functions have an applicative/monad instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631242/use-cases-for-functor-applicative-monad-instances-for-functions). But I see no reason to use the monad instance over the applicative (other than dropping a `flip`). So I'd ask the author, why not `isPalindromA = (==) <*> reverse`?

Comment: @Micha I totally agree, especially since I find the applicative form more transparent. My question was aimed more toward “why does this monadic expression work?”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It took me some time to find the monad, and since it is not related to `List`, I figured I'd post an answer.

The expression `reverse >>= (==)` implies the type of `reverse` is `m a`, for some monad `m`, hence `m a` is the type `[c] -> [c]`. We also need `isPalindromeM` to have type `[c] -> Bool`, and the bind expression implies `m b` is identical to `[c] -> Bool`. Finally this context requires `(==) :: [c] -> [c] -> Bool` to have the type `a -> m b`.

Therefore we deduce `a` is `[c]` and `b` is `Bool`, and the monad `m` takes a type `a` and sends it to the function type `[c] -> a`. This suggests the monad at play is `Monad ((->) [c])`. [defined here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad)

If there's some moral to the story, perhaps it's "you can make a monad out of anything".

Comment: Basically right, but I'd make the small nit that the monad instance is technically `((->) [c])`, i.e. it has been specialized to `r ~ [c]`. `((->) r)` is a monad for any `r`, and in your case `r` is `[c]`.

Comment: One way to check whether a piece of code uses the list monad is to check what is "send" into `(>>=)`. In your case `reverse >>= ...`. Since `reverse` is not a list, this is not the list monad.